# How do you address a question that's been flagged as a duplicate?

Tags: support

A question I asked has been flagged as a duplicate, I believe incorrectly. When I looked up what to do here the advice was to edit it to explain why it wasn't, which I did, and then flagged it when that didn't seem to work. However, I have gotten no response at all, either removing the duplicate flag or reaffirming that it should be there. What is the procedure in these situations?

Comment: That looks like it says to edit the question, which I have already done.

Comment: When did you [edit] it?  What is the URL of your question?

Comment: I edited it I believe a few hours after it was flagged. The URL is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385742/proof-by-induction-for-mn-choose-nr-sum-limits-k-0mm-choose-kn).

Comment: From doing a little snooping, I found that your post [had already been reviewed for reopening, but the reviewers assessed that it should remain closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/1261900). Because of the way the reopen review system works, you should make your *first* edit after your question is closed completely reflect why it should be reopened. Your only option here, I'm afraid, is to make a request on the per-site meta (Mathematics Meta) clearly explaining why the mark should be removed.